# how can i change the size of (particular one)cell which is the part of uitableview(grouped) iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i change the size of (particular one)cell which is the part of uitableview(grouped) iphone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change the height of the cell in UiTableView. (i.e. you can give different height for different cell) But can't change the width for any particular cell.

You can use this delegate method to change the height of cell

**- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**